# Should i use LEFT JOIN OR INNER JOIN or RIGHT JOIN for joining 3 different query into a single query

Tags: php, mysql

FIRST QUERY

```
$sql="SELECT distinct(syllabus.syllabusName) as subjectName,$cid as courseId, stud.batchId as batchId,course.courseId,course.syllabusId AS subjectID,course.unitId,stud.studentID as studentID  ,concat(stud.studentFirstName,' ',stud.studentLastName,' ',stud.studentRegistrationNumber) AS studentName
            FROM studentdetails  stud           
            INNER JOIN  `coursemapping` course 
            ON  stud.`courseId`=course.courseId
            INNER JOIN syllabus syllabus
            ON  course.syllabusId=syllabus.syllabusId 
            WHERE course.courseId ='$cid' AND course.syllabusId='$sid' AND stud.`batchId`='$bid'";
```

SECOND QUERY

```
     $sql=" SELECT A.assignmentId, A.unitId, B.assignmentName, C.assignmentsBatchId AS batchId, C.courseId AS courseId,C.assignmentMappingId, D.studentId, concat( E.studentFirstName, ' ', E.studentLastName, ' ', E.studentRegistrationNumber ) AS studentName
            FROM studentdetails E
            INNER JOIN assignmentscompleted D ON E.studentId = D.studentId
            INNER JOIN assignmentsbatch C ON D.assignmentId = C.assignmentMappingId
            INNER JOIN assignments B ON D.assignmentId = B.assignmentId
            INNER JOIN assignmentsMapping A ON B.assignmentId = A.assignmentId
            WHERE A.assignmentId = '$sid'
            AND C.assignmentsBatchId = '$bid'
            AND C.courseId ='$cid'";
```

THIRD QUERY

```
    $sql    =   "SELECT distinct(C.syllabusName) as subjectName,B.maxAccadamicMarks as marksScored,B.academicMarks as maxMarks,B.marksPercentage as percentage  
                    FROM studentdetails A INNER JOIN marks B 
                    ON A.studentId=B.studentId AND A.courseId=B.courseId AND A.batchId=B.batchId 
                    INNER JOIN syllabus C 
                    ON  B.syllabusId=C.syllabusId WHERE A.studentUserName='$studentUserName'";
```

Here i need to join all the three query in order to fetch the subject,student,accmarks,marks,percentage? how to join all this three query to single query

Comment: Offhand, I'll say you can't join these queries into a single one, as they're fetching different types of data, even if some of the tables involved are the same.

Comment: Why do you need/want to run these all as a single query? If you're fetching apples, oranges, and mud, then fetch them separately instead of trying to bake them all into a mud-flavored fruit pie.

Comment: Why do you want to join these 3 unjoinable queries together instead of writing a new query to pull just the data you want?

Comment: but i need all these apples,oranges and mud in a single table to be displayed

Comment: @Paul in order to fetch the marks of assignment,events and subject marks of a particular student

Comment: Yes, I get that, but why not make a new query from scratch?  As @MarcB pointed out, you can't join them together. Perhaps it would be easier if you selected the results of each query into 3 tables, then queried those tables for what you need.

Comment: @dude: so? You can run the 3 queries separately, store their results, then use a separate bit of code to mesh/merge/display those results. It'd be FAR easier than trying to come up with some utterly ugly unreadable/unmaintainble query to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Hmmm fine wil query into a new one...but the prob is that the assignment subject names and subject names wil clash

Comment: If your query is done right then the names won't clash - they'd better be the same if you select them both. If someone has a grade for "history.assignment1" and the subject is "math" then either your query or your database has problems!

Comment: please update your post and tell us the definitions of your tables as well as the desired result table. I think we will be able to find a fast solution then.

Comment: i wrote a new query and its working... Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you would likely be able to merge the queries together quite easily as many are using common tables, but without a table structure I am just writing a quick and dirty mashup or the three queries you have provided. I am assuming that each of these queries retuns exactly what you need and nothing else.

I have altered the third query just so slightly to add in the studentID so that it can be properly joined with the other queries and also commented out redundant information in the second query.

```
select
    a.studentID as studentID,
    a.studentName as studentName,
    $cid as courseID,
    a.batchID as batchID,
    a.subjectID as subjectID,
    c.subjectName as subjectName,
    a.unitID as unitID,
    b.assignmentID as assignmentID,
    b.assignmentName as assignmentName,
    b.assignmentMappingID as assignmentMappingID,
    c.marksScored as marksScored,
    c.maxMarks as maxMarks,
    c.percentage as percentageMarks
from
(
    select 
        distinct(syllabus.syllabusName) as subjectName,
        $cid as courseID, 
        stud.batchId as batchID,
        course.courseID,
        course.syllabusId as subjectID,
        course.unitID,
        stud.studentID as studentID  ,
        concat(stud.studentFirstName,' ',stud.studentLastName,' ',stud.studentRegistrationNumber) AS studentName
    FROM 
        studentdetails  stud           
            INNER JOIN  `coursemapping` course 
                ON  stud.`courseId`=course.courseId
            INNER JOIN syllabus syllabus
                ON  course.syllabusId=syllabus.syllabusId 
    WHERE 
        course.courseId ='$cid' 
        AND course.syllabusId='$sid' 
        AND stud.`batchId`='$bid'
) a,
(
    SELECT 
        A.assignmentID, 
        A.unitID, 
        B.assignmentName, 
        C.assignmentsBatchId AS batchID, 
        C.courseId AS courseID,
        C.assignmentMappingID, 
        D.studentID, 
        --concat( E.studentFirstName, ' ', E.studentLastName, ' ', E.studentRegistrationNumber ) AS studentName
    FROM 
        studentdetails E
            INNER JOIN assignmentscompleted D 
                ON E.studentId = D.studentId
            INNER JOIN assignmentsbatch C 
                ON D.assignmentId = C.assignmentMappingId
            INNER JOIN assignments B 
                ON D.assignmentId = B.assignmentId
            INNER JOIN assignmentsMapping A 
                ON B.assignmentId = A.assignmentId
    WHERE 
        A.assignmentId = '$sid'
        AND C.assignmentsBatchId = '$bid'
        AND C.courseId ='$cid'
) b,
(
    SELECT 
        distinct(C.syllabusName) as subjectName,
        B.maxAccadamicMarks as marksScored,
        B.academicMarks as maxMarks,
        B.marksPercentage as percentage,
        A.studentID,
        a.courseID as courseID
    FROM 
        studentdetails A 
            INNER JOIN marks B 
                ON A.studentId=B.studentId 
                AND A.courseId=B.courseId 
                AND A.batchId=B.batchId 
            INNER JOIN syllabus C 
                ON  B.syllabusId=C.syllabusId 
    WHERE 
        A.studentUserName='$studentUserName'
) c
where
    a.studentID=b.studentID
    and a.studentID=c.studentID
    and a.courseID=b.courseID
    and a.courseID=c.courseID
```

That *should* work without getting a cartesian join on the individual queries, but again is difficult to be sure without a table structure.

Having said all that, I do totally agree with some of the commentors above, by merging all these queries you will get a recordset that will have certain bits of information repeated over and over on each line that are useless to you. You may well be better off running one query, popping the values into variables and then just using them as needed.